# Open Specific Word document from Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to open a specific word document from microsoft excel. I have the following code:

```
    Dim WordApp As Object, WordDoc As Object, FileToOpen As String

Sub Generate_Report()

FileToOpen = "C:\Users\david\resource letter.docx"
Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileToOpen)
WordApp.Visible = True

End Sub
```

But when I run the code it fails on the Set WordDoc = WordAppDocuments.Open(FiletoOpen) line, says that I am missing an object.

I've tried to use the documentsopen function. I've tried feeding it a document or file type instead of a string. I previously made sure that the names are aligned for the objects, so that the word document at least in theory should be an object of the word application. Also, have tried changed the syntax to

```
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open Filename =: "C:\Users\david\resource letter.docx"
```

but VBA throws that as a syntax error (not sure why). Help!

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? It looks to me like it's missing something like "Desktop" or "Documents".

Comment: `=:` should be `:=`

Comment: @braX yeah I'm sure it's correct. I didn't include it in the comment here but the full path is something that I got manually on my machine

Comment: @Warcupine Hey thanks! That was a great catch, and helps me get through the syntax error. But I still haven't figured out my issue.

Comment: Try `If WordApp Is Nothing Then: MsgBox "No Word App": Else: Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileToOpen): End If` to see whether WordApp is successfully created or not.

Comment: I literally changed nothing except added this code in and it worked. Why did this work?!

Answer (score 0):

this code works for me:

First, please ensure you have referenced the "Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library" via Tools -> References

```
Sub OpenDoc()
    Dim strFile As String

    strFile = "C:\Users\LIUIO\OneDrive - LANXESS Deutschland GmbH\Dokumente\Macro Files\USERFORM.docx"    'change to path of your file
    If Dir(strFile) <> "" Then    'to check if document exists at the given location
        Documents.Open strFile
    End If
End Sub
```